# bower let me not upgrade to angularjs 1.3.2

Tags: angularjs, bower

Why can I not upgrade from angular 1.2.23 to 1.3.2 when I do

C:\MyTestProject>bower update angular --save --latest

in my terminal?

Then I get this as message:

```
bower angular#>= 1.0.8          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.2
bower angular#>= 1.0.8        validate 1.3.2 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#1.2.23            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.23
bower angular#1.2.23          validate 1.2.23 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.23
bower angular#>=1               cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.2
bower angular#>=1             validate 1.3.2 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1
bower angular#1.2.26            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.26
bower angular#1.2.26          validate 1.2.26 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.26
bower angular#>=1.0.0 <1.4.0    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.2
bower angular#>=1.0.0 <1.4.0  validate 1.3.2 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.0.0 <1.4.0

Please note that,
    MyTestProject depends on angular#1.2.23 which resolved to angular#1.2.23
    angular-mocks#1.2.26 depends on angular#1.2.26 which resolved to angular#1.2.26
    angular-ui-router#0.2.12 depends on angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to angular#1.3.2
    angular-bootstrap#0.11.2 depends on angular#>=1 which resolved to angular#1.3.2
    angular-moment#0.8.2 depends on angular#>=1.0.0 <1.4.0 which resolved to angular#1.3.2
Resort to using angular#1.2.23 which resolved to angular#1.2.23
Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

Is the problem the angular-mocks?

UPDATE

```
{
  "name": "angular-mocks",
  "version": "",
  "description": "AngularJS mocks for testing",
  "main": "angular-mocks.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.js.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "framework",
    "browser",
    "mocks",
    "testing",
    "client-side"
  ],
  "author": "Angular Core Team <angular-core+npm@google.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "http://angularjs.org"
}
```

**.bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-mocks",
  "version": "1.2.26",
  "main": "./angular-mocks.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.26"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks",
  "_release": "1.2.26",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v1.2.26",
    "commit": "0eda339dd42aba2628586f39d4806bcfb57fd6f4"
  },
  "_source": "git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git",
  "_target": "~1.2.23",
  "_originalSource": "angular-mocks"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, bump it up so it matches your angular version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have `angular-mocks` locked in to a particular version range that doesn't allow bower to upgrade it to 1.3.2 (need to see your `bower.json` to tell for sure). When you upgrade your core angular to a new version, make sure you also match the version rule for all other angular core packages which depend on your main `angular` package, i.e. they need to be in sync:

```
# in bower.json
"devependencies": {
  angular: ^1.3.2
  ... ... ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  angular-mocks: ^1.3.2
... ... ...
}
```

After you've updated the `package.json`,  run `bower update` to update your local packages.

Examples of Angular 1.3 core packages are:

- angular-mocks.js
- angular-scenario.js
- angular-animate.js
- angular-cookies.js
- angular-resource.js
- angular-route.js
- angular-sanitize.js
- angular-touch.js

Comment: You saved my day (if not my week... :-)